# Input Email que solo permita un dominio

Tags: jquery, mvc

Quiero hacer un *input* que por default tenga `@empresa.com` y no se pueda cambiar, osea que la persona solo coloque su correo antes del `@`.

```js
@ {
  var correo = "@empresa.com";
  <input class = "form-control"
  type = "email"
  name = "name"
  value = "@correo" / >
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ¿qué intentaste?

Comment: @Marcelo, recomendaría que edites tu pregunta: [edit] y que revises [repro]. Tener código base ayuda a entender mejor la pregunta.

Comment: mi codigo razor es :                                                                                                      
@{

    var correo = "@empresa.com";
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="name" value="@correo" />
}

Comment: Pon el código dentro de la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo el siguiente código, la explicación en cada línea.

```js
$("#email").keyup(function(){ //Analizamos cada vez que se presione una tecla
  let val = $(this).val(); //Capturamos el valor del input
  let index = val.indexOf("@"); //Buscamos la existencia del símbolo @
  if(index > -1){ //Si el símbolo existe procedemos a eliminarlo
    val = val.substring(0, index);
    $(this).val(val);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="email"> @empresa.com
```

Al final cuando vayas a usar el email solo es que le concatenes el @empresa.com para que lo tengas completo.